# Rails - List a all items method in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to list all my lawns in one page and then all my bookings in another page. I am writing a method in my controller to list my all items in my database but the problem is either it displays 1 in the view or it produces an inheritance error(in the view) . What I have so far is a lawn that has_many bookings (should actually be has one booking) and a booking which belongs to a lawn and everything is controlled through Activeadmin. The error I get is

> undefined method `description' for
>   Lawn::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007f4451b00a58> I have modified the error a little bit so it can show over here.

Here is my controller code. A lawn has a title and a description so I am not sure why I get the error. I have put 2 different methods for lawn and booking but they are both not working. Here is my controller.

```
def display_lawns
    @lawn = Lawn.all
  end

  def display_status
    @lawn = Lawn.where("selected = ?", "true")
    @bookings = @lawn.booking
  end
```

And here is my view file which does not seem to work with the Lawn.all I also have a similar view file for the bookings with a few changes.

```
<h2><%= @lawn.description %></h2>
<ul>
  <% @lawn.bookings.each do |booking| %>
    <li>
      <%= booking.description %>
      <%= button_to "Select", update_booking_path(booking_id: booking), remote: true %>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of hints.

Instead of

```
@lawn = Lawn.where("selected = ?", "true")
```

Is better to add a scope in your model.
@lawn is an array of objects, so use plural.

```
  def display_lawns
    @lawns = Lawn.all
  end

  def display_status
   @lawns = Lawn.all.where("selected = ?", "true")
  end
```

@lawns is an array, so you can't use `@lawn.description`

`@lawn.first.description` works if you need the first item of the array

```
<h2><%= @lawns.first.description %></h2>
<ul>
  <% @lawns.each do |lawn| %>
    <li>
      <%= lawn.description %>
      <%= button_to "Select", update_booking_path(booking_id: lawn.booking), remote: true %>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

`Lawn.all` and `Lawn.where(...)` return an [ActiveRecord::Relation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html), consisting of multiple lawns.

In your view, you try to display a lawn's description via `@lawn.description`, but `@lawn` is not a single lawn object, but a collection of lawn objects, and the collection does not have a description.

Either only show one lawn object, or loop over all the objects in `@lawn` (and rename it to `@lawns`).

Comment: I am now getting an ActiveRecord Relation error, it says undefined method `description'. The error is in the view file. I have tried using both all and where.

Comment: I need to list all the lawns rather than just one lawn so the @lawns.first.description will now work for me.